# Have a class variable change a property without calling a method

Tags: swift, class, methods, uikit

I just started using UIKit elements in swift. I made a subclass from UILabel called Text() with a new variable named x. I want x to go in a CGRect strut like this

```
CGRect(x: self.x, y: Self.y, width: self.width, height: self.height)
```

But I have to run a method to do this is there a way run a method when I call the variable like this?

```
text.x = 5
```

Comment: Yes: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID259

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare the property, you can use `didSet` to trigger an action. E.g.

```
class Text: UILabel
{
    var x: CGFloat {
        didSet {
            CGRect(x: self.x, y: self.y, width: self.width, height: self.height)
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Note that `didSet` is not called during initialization, i.e. not in `init()`, nor in `var x = CGFloat( 5 )`.